# Градл ругается на файл и не может собрать проект

Tags: android, gradle

Вобщем подключил библиотеку `compile 'com.specyci:residemenu:1.6+'` в проект.
При запуске выдает ошибку

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    C:\Users\zen_75\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\22.0.0\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output C:\projects\android-customer\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=C:\projects\android-customer\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
Error Code:
    2
Output:
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:502)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:277)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:491)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:168)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:1
```

06)

Попробовал сделать эксклуд но наверное не правильно

```
 packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/inputList'
    }
```

не могу понять что делать. на демке эта либа работает. Но там подключена как модуль а не как градл. может кто сталкивался? Ах да проект синхронизируется, ошибка при старте, когда нажимаю ран.

Comment: для .dex файлов (в которые собирается ваш java код) есть ограничение в 65535 методов максимум. Тоесть получается, что весь ваш проект вместе с библиотеками содержит больше методов. Исправить это можно разделив его на несколько dex файлов при помощи DexClassLoader

Comment: Добавьте секцию dependencies из build.gradle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данное исключение возникает из-за ограничений формата DEX

> You can reference a very large number of methods in a DEX file, but
>   you can only invoke the first 65536, because that’s all the room you
>   have in the method invocation instruction

Для решения данной проблемы необходимо убрать ненужные библиотеки (например для google-play-services использовать только [необходимые модули](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) из таблицы 1). Так же можно избавиться от разбиения на большое количество методов.

Если у вас есть классы моделей, то стоит избавиться в них от геттеров/сеттеров и сделать public поля (**только** если в методах нет дополнительной логики)

Comment: Еще не забываем использовать proguard.